# 403 Forbidden for direct URL access of custom module file

Tags: module, magento-1

I am working on a specific PHP file in my custom module and would like to run it in a browser to debug but am getting 403 Forbidden.

Is there a way to directly access http://domain.com/app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/Model/Filename.php?

Alternatively, is there a better way to be testing specific module files?

Answer (score 0):

James,In magento,**files under** app folder **does not access using this type code.**

As per as,your code,i guess that **you should study Magento, and it vast structure**.

In above question, you have create a  module's a model class.But in order to access model you **should define a module and model class**

**Follow the below links for magento study:**

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643

Comment: Yes, I've done this and my module is running on a cronjob schedule every 5 minutes.  I just want to be able to fire my code instantaneously for debugging purposes.  I have created a file in my root directory that does this, however, is there not some developer mode that allows one to do this?